# How to convert interface{} to []int?

Tags: go

I am programming in Go programming language.

Say there's a variable of type `interface{}` that contains an array of integers. How do I convert `interface{}` back to `[]int`?

I have tried

```
interface_variable.([]int)
```

The error I got is:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is []interface {}, not []int
```

Comment: Can you include code? (ps: []int is not an array of integers, it's a slice of integers).

Comment: You need to iterate over the slice of interface{} using range and copy the asserted ints into a new slice.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Related: http://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a `[]interface{}` not just one `interface{}`, you have to loop through it and convert it:

#### the 2022 answer

https://go.dev/play/p/yeihkfIZ90U

```golang
func ConvertSlice[E any](in []any) (out []E) {
    out = make([]E, 0, len(in))
    for _, v := range in {
        out = append(out, v.(E))
    }
    return
}
```

#### the pre-go1.18 answer

http://play.golang.org/p/R441h4fVMw

```
func main() {
    a := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    b := make([]int, len(a))
    for i := range a {
        b[i] = a[i].(int)
    }
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Comment: When I did `range a`, the compiler says that you cannot iterate []interface{}

Comment: what version of go do you have? type `go version`, it works fine http://play.golang.org/p/R441h4fVMw

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you should iterate the slice and convert the objects one by one.
Is better to use a type switch inside the range in order to avoid panics:

```
a := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
b := make([]int, len(a))
for i, value := range a {
    switch typedValue := value.(type) {
    case int:
        b[i] = typedValue
        break
    default:
        fmt.Println("Not an int: ", value)
    }
}
fmt.Println(a, b)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Kbs3rbu2Rw

Comment: Unnecessary overhead if you know it will always be an `[]int`, also should be `fmt.Println("Not an int: ", value)`.

Comment: If you know it will always be a slice of int, then it's unnecessary to start with a slice of interface{}. When making conversions or dealing with type assertions it is always a best practice to test if the items are one of the types you're expecting. I'll edit the code, thanks for noting the typo.

Comment: @rvignacio: In Go, we do not require an explicit `break` in `switch` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Func return value is interface{} but real return value is []interface{}, so try this instead:

```
func main() {
    values := returnValue.([]interface{})
    for i := range values {
        fmt.Println(values[i])
    }
}
```